# My c program prints "out of memory"-error but there are lots of memory space available

Tags: c, memory, dev-c++

My program returns memory error without using even more than 1 MB. I write C in dev-cpp compiler. The original program is too large to put it here. This very simple program works for me:

`int main(){int a[520076]; return 0;}`

and returns value 0. However, this:

`int main(){int a[520077]; return 0;}`

Does not work and the reason is memory. I use Windows 8 but the same problem comes up in Windows 7.
Looks like the system puts a limit on memory space that can be used by a process. May the boundary also be put in place by dev-cpp?

Answer (score 5):

> Looks like the system puts a maximum memory space

Yes, but this not exactly is the problem in this case. The array you declare is local and automatic, so it's most likely allocated on the stack. Stack space is limited, even more limited than dynamically allocated memory (which is usually on the heap), and with its few megabytes large size (if I recall correctly, it's actually 1 single MB on Windows by default), it quickly collides with other memory areas.

If you don't want this, declare your variable as a file-scope ("global") variable or as `static` (read up on the side effects).

Also, you're right in that the OS also limits **all** the memory - it tries to maintain democracy between processes. Even if you run a program on a server with 128 gigabytes of RAM, `malloc()` will likely fail, for example, if you're trying to allocate 32 gigabytes. That much memory should not be needed in general and the OS protects other processes from one erroneously (or intentionally) eating up resources.

Comment: or malloc/free it yourself instead of declaring it like this

Comment: @Daij-Djan If it isn't meant to be passed around for a long time across functions, then it's superfluous to `malloc()`ate it.

Comment: makes sense. just an option :D

Comment: Thanks for your response.Is there a way to increase the stack size with a system command or sth; Else what are the main side effects that i would have by making it static. I know how static works in a function but not in main!? Please advise.

Comment: @JohnSig [I think there is.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx) But I'm by no means a Windows expert.

Comment: What are the main side effects that i would have by making it static. I know how static works in a function but not in main!? Please advise.

Comment: @JohnSig **`main()` is a function.**

Comment: Depends on the compiler, I think Visual studio has a \STACK_SIZE parameter

Comment: I know that but the point is that in the programs that i am used to main is used once in the program and so i do not understand the real difference that it has if a variable is defined as auto or as static.Please adviise.(Thanks a lot for your previous responses)

Comment: @JohnSig It's either in the stack (if it's an automatic variable) or somewhere else (BSS? Zero-initialized data?) if it's `static`.

Comment: Static does not work in my original program unfortunately so now i believe my real problem is malloc(). What command can i use that will dynamically allocate memory but will not fail as you said;

Comment: But you said malloc will fail!

Comment: @JohnSig If you request too much memory.